# Меню не работает на IE7

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня такая проблема. сделал меню на jQurey меню работает нормально кроме на IE7. меню не реагирует ни на что. Подскажите пожалуйста чем проблема.
**Код - HTML**

```
<body>
                <ul id="list">
                          <li id="1">Ссылка1<span class="list1">[<span id="list1">0</span>]</span></li>
                          <li id="2">Cсылка2<span class="list1">[<span id="list2">0</span>]</span></li>
                          <li id="3">Ссылка3<span class="list1">[<span id="list3">0</span>]</span></li>
                          <li id="4">Ссылка4<span class="list1">[<span id="list4">0</span>]</span></li>
                          <li id="5">Ссылка5<span class="list1">[<span id="list5">0</span>]</span></li>
                </ul>
```

**Код - CSS**

```
  #list .list1 {display:none;
                float:right;
                margin-right:180px;
                }
 #list {background:silver;
        width:381px;
        list-style:none;
        border:1px solid #000;
        }
  #list li { width:281px;
             height:21px;
             background:url(../img/menu-line.gif) no-repeat;
             color:blue;
             fons-size:15px;
             padding-left:60px;
             }
  .noactive {
  margin-left:20px;
  }
  .active { 
  margin-left:0px;
  }
```

**Код - JQuery**

```
$(function() {
     $('#list li').click(function() {

          var current = $(this);    
          var id = current.attr('id');
          var str = "#list"+ id;
          var number = parseInt($(str).text());
          number = number +1;

          $(this).find('span.list1').show();

         if (number <5)
         {  
           $(str).html(number);
           $('li').each(function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','0'); 
               });
                  $('li').each(function() {          
                          $(this).animate({
                                    width: "70%",
                                    marginLeft: "0.4in",
                                    fontSize: "1em",
                                  }, 500 );
        }); 
        current.animate({margin:'0'},
                {duration:1000}); 
         }
         else {
             $(this).remove();
         }
     })
 })
```

Comment: в названии браузера?)

Comment: не в названии а в нем самом :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. все дело в magrin 
current.next().animate({marginLeft:'20px'},{duration:200});
Спасибо всем кто откликнулся на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу можно выделить

```
`fontSize: "1em",`
```

запятая лишняя

Comment: Заработало. только на один клик.а при повторном клике меню опять зависло. и еще куда-то пропали фигурные скобки.
 Кстати вот задание что необходима должна делать меню 
 При клике на ссылку все остальные сдвигаются в сторону.
При клике на другую ссылку сначала все возвращаются на исходную позицию, а затем сдвигаются относительно текущей,как в п. 1.
 После клика на ссылке в ее текст добавляется в конец счетчик кликов (например, «Ссылка [2]»), а при каждом клике значение счетчика увеличивается. До первого клика ссылка счетчика не имеет («Ссылка»).
 После  (5) кликов ссылка исчезает из списка.

Comment: оно наверное не зависло, а произошла js-ошибка, включите вывод ошибок в ие, чтоб видеть сообщения, кстати, еще заметил current.animate({margin:'0'}, наверное должно быть {marginRight:'0'}